# R mailR package issues with sending message to STMP Server (gmail)

Tags: r, email, sendmailr

I have been toying around with the mailR package to send emails from my Gmail account, but so far I have been unable to make it work. The code is as following (with emails and passwords replaced with 'aaaa' for privacy/security):

```
library(mailR)

sender <- 'aaaa@gmail.com'
recipients <- c('aaaa@gmail.com')
send.mail(from = sender,
              to = recipients,
              subject = 'My bot sent this',
              body = 'Test Successful',
              smtp = list(host.name = 'stmp.gmail.com', port= 587,
                               user.name = 'aaaa@gmail.com',
                               passwd = 'aaaa', tls= TRUE),
              authenticate = TRUE,
              send = TRUE)
```

From my understanding this appears to be an appropriate set up for this package. Furthermore I have made sure double sign in is off and 'Access allowed for less secure apps' is enabled. I have also tried this with both tls and ssl (complete with appropriate ports), which has not made a difference.

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : stmp.gmail.com:587
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: stmp.gmail.com, 587; timeout 60000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: stmp.gmail.com
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2053)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: stmp.gmail.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:310)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
    ... 13 more
NULL
Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : stmp.gmail.com:587
```

For the record, here is the traceback output as well:

```
> traceback()
10: stop(list(message = "org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : stmp.gmail.com:587", 
        call = .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", 
            cl, .jcast(if (inherits(o, "jobjRef") || inherits(o, 
                "jarrayRef")) o else cl, "java/lang/Object"), .jnew("java/lang/String", 
                method), j_p, j_pc, use.true.class = TRUE, evalString = simplify, 
            evalArray = FALSE), jobj = <S4 object of class "jobjRef">))
9: .Call(RJavaCheckExceptions, silent)
8: .jcheck(silent = FALSE)
7: .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl, 
       .jcast(if (inherits(o, "jobjRef") || inherits(o, "jarrayRef")) o else cl, 
           "java/lang/Object"), .jnew("java/lang/String", method), 
       j_p, j_pc, use.true.class = TRUE, evalString = simplify, 
       evalArray = FALSE)
6: .jrcall(x, name, ...)
5: email$send() at MessageBot.R#15
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(ei, envir)
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
1: source("MessageBot.R")
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer given that you've asked for a trouble shooting solution using the `mailr` package, but if you're open to trying another package use `gmailr`.

```
install.packages('gmailr')
library(gmailr)
setwd() #set to desired working directory
gmail_auth()

mail <- mime(
  To = "to_address@domain.com",
  From = "from_address@domain.com",
  Subject = "My bot sent this",
  body = "Test successful")
send_message(mail)
```

When you use the `gmail_auth` function, it will interactively ask if you want to connect to your gmail account. Please note by using the gmailR package you are connecting through a public application.

By entering 'yes' in the terminal and clicking 'accept' in the browser you are storing a `.httr-auth` token (encrypted user name and password) in your current working directory (why we set the working directory at the beginning). You can see the file by running `list.files(all = T)` in the terminal. This allows you to rerun code without having to a.) store your user name a password in the physical code and b.) 're-accept' the connection interactively.

Comment: I will give that a shot, though I'm still open to answers about how to make this work in mailR!

Answer (score 0):

You insert the wrong hostname: `host.name = 'stmp.gmail.com'`
The protocol is smtp, so `host.name = 'smtp.gmail.com'`